# Why does text content in fragment overlapping with tabs in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I have three tabs like personal,medical and insurance. In personal tab i have 4 fields like name,email id,DOB and phone number. I have used `android:inputType=Phone` for entering phone number. When I enter phone number, all the above fields are moved and overlapped with personal tab. can anyone pls tell me how to resolve this issue?
[image]

**Edit**

Solved this issue : `android:layout_below="@id/tabs"`

Add this line in the activity layout where you call those three layouts

Comment: can you show the three tab layout ?

Comment: You did not get me, I was asked you to show the tab host layout of activity where you load the three fragment for each tab click

Comment: try to add following in your Menifest at particular activity tag android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Comment: will it wrk fr sure??

Answer (score 0):

You have used `ScrollView` thats why your all fields moved up whenever you open keypad which is correct... Post tab layout
Give some solid color to `tabHost` and check....It looks like `tabHost` is transparent

Comment: I have given color for that tabs and tried. but still got the same problem. may i knw what is the diff between with color in tabHost and without color in tabHost

Comment: Post tabhost layout if you seriously wants an answer

Comment: Yes I asked her to post the tab host layout. I think the issue in it.

Comment: actually i am newbie to android. this code part is done by my colleague. thats why i am unable to get ur point.sory for the trouble. http://paste.ofcode.org/ccijNwRHDazSRwqgM6Dyk4 did u ask this code?

Comment: I think you did not implemented the tab host, I do not understand the screen layout. The problem you showing it might be due to of the tab host layout you define in your layout.

Comment: Ok let me check it out

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file, give following attribute in your activity tag.

```
<activity android:name="activity name" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
</activity>
```